# foreach statement forcing while/for to loop too many times

Tags: php, html, foreach, while-loop

I have a `while/for` loop with a `foreach` loop inside. Reading the code will make it self explanatory as to what I am trying to achieve in terms of logic.

In layman's terms, I am trying to create a calendar in PHP. The `foreach` statement creates 35 cells, for the calendar interface, 4 weeks, 7 days, 5 x 7 = 35.

The `while` loop has taken the number of days in April (30) and trying to each the range 1-30 in each cell.

However, when implementing the code below, each number gets iterated 30 times.

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 30){
    foreach ($this->cells as $cells){
        foreach ($cells as $key => $object){
            echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";                     
            if($object % 7 == 0){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }  
    }
    $i++;   
}
```

I tried this:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 30){
    foreach ($this->cells as $cells){
        foreach ($cells as $key => $object){
            echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";  $i++;                              
            if($object % 7 == 0){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }  
    }

}
```

Which instead of outputting 1-30 many times each, it outputs 1-35, when I only want 1-30.

I have tried a for loop with the result it prints many of each number. For loop code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++){
                foreach ($this->cells as $cells){
                    foreach ($cells as $key => $object){
                echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";             
                if($object % 7 == 0){
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                }
                    }  
                }   
            }
```

`$this->cells` is a range 1-35 in an array

Comment: Why don't you use a `for()` loop instead of that `while()`?

Comment: because i was unfamiliar with it. would maybe still present the same problem, if just changing the word while to for

Comment: how is it 4*7 = 35?..please explain..

Comment: In the second code you are incrementing `$i` twice in your loop. Is that really your intention?

Comment: sorry, 5x7. sorry, not meant to increment twice. thanks

Comment: see update for my for loop code which didnt work.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve :| You want 35 blank cells with the first 30 populated with the numbers 1-30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i=0;
foreach ($this->cells as $cells){
    foreach ($cells as $key => $object){
        if($i<=30)
            echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
        $i++;                              
        if($object % 7 == 0){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Try this code

Comment: this is brilliant answer and has helped me. I however changed $i=0 to $i=1, because i want the first cell with 1. This code does present one problem however, there are 5 cells (35-30) which get forgotton, i would still like those cells to have a <td></td>

Comment: then put this line after my IF loop, ELSE echo '<td>&bnsp;</td>';

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=0;
while ($i++ < 35){
    echo '<td>' . ($i <= 30 ? $i : '&nbsp;') . '</td>';
    if($i % 7 == 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    } 
}
```

I'm not really sure why you need to do two loops, you could do it all with one (unless you do need to loop over `$this->cells`, in which case ignore this answer :p)